# C Program terminates after if/else or repeats if I use fputs/fgets

Tags: c, stdin, scanf, fgets, fputs

I am very new to C and have dabbled in Objective-C, AppleScript, and HTML/CSS. I'm sure that my problem is very easy to solve. I am trying to write something that will allow me to input source data and have it ordered in a certain way as output (in this case, citations). Basically, I want to save name, title, publisher, etc. as variables and print them in a certain order.

Here's the issue: The code here terminates too early and when I use fputs and fgets with stdout and stdin it gets stuck and asks the same question forever. What am I missing?

```
int source_type;
int NumberofAuthors;
char AuthorName1[20];
char AuthorName2[20];
char AuthorName3[20];
char title[20];
char url[100];
char publishingCity[20];
char publisher[20];
char yearPublished[20];
char pageNumbers[20];
int valid;

printf("Welcome to Jackson's Chicago Manual of Style Auto-Footnoter.\n");

fputs("Choose source type:\n a.Book\n b.Journal\n c.Article\n d.Website\n ", stdout);
source_type = getchar();

if (source_type == 'a') {
    valid = 1;
} else {
    printf("Invalid source selection");
}

while ( valid == 1 && source_type == 'a' )
{
    printf("Number of authors [1 or 2]: ");
    scanf( "%d", &NumberofAuthors);
    if ( NumberofAuthors > 0 && NumberofAuthors < 3 ) {
        valid = 1;
        printf("Got it, %d author(s).\n", NumberofAuthors);
    }
    else {
        printf( "That's not enough people to write a book.\n" );
    }

    if ( NumberofAuthors == 1 ) {
        printf( "Author's name: " );
        scanf("%c", &AuthorName1);

    } 
    if (NumberofAuthors == 2) {
        printf("First author's name: " );
        scanf("%c", &AuthorName2);
        printf("Second author's name: " );
        scanf("%c", &AuthorName3);
    }
    else {
        valid = 0;
    }

    printf("Book title: " );
    fgets(title, sizeof(title), stdin);

    printf("Publication city: " );
    fgets(publishingCity, sizeof(publishingCity), stdin);


    } 


return 0;
```

Comment: First of all, when fetching strings with `scanf`, use `%s` instead, and you don't need the `&` for the char-arrays.

Comment: I took out the '&' and it skipped 'while' altogether...

Comment: Then there is something else wrong, as the code you supposedly changed is all inside the loop and doesn't have anything to do with the loop condition. Also, is there a reason you are using `fgets` to get some strings, but not for others?

Comment: Honestly, the `fgets` thing is because they were all originally as they are here, then I read that I shouldn't use `scanf`, so I changed it to `fgets` and the whole thing was useless. I changed it back (except for the few you see) and have been dealing with the hang-ups since.

Taking another look at the `&`'s.

Comment: Took out the `&`'s again and got a bad access signal at `scanf( "%d", NumberofAuthors);`

Comment: Only remove the `&` on the strings you get with `scanf`. That is because they are already pointers. When you do `scanf` on single characters (`%c`) or integers (`%d`) then you need the address of the variable to store the value, with strings (`char *` or `char x[] = ".."`) then the variable itself already is an address.

Comment: aaAAAAaaah. Thanks! Any ideas about why it's stopping at the `if ( NumberofAuthors == 1 ) {` line?

Answer (score 1):

On the beggining of the program:

```
if (source_type == 'a') {
    valid = 1;
} else {
    printf("Invalid source selection");
}
```

In case `source_type` is invalid, `valid` still contains garbage value, and using an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour. Moving on.

```
while ( valid == 1 && source_type == 'a' )
{
    printf("Number of authors [1 or 2]: ");
    scanf( "%d", &NumberofAuthors);
    if ( NumberofAuthors > 0 && NumberofAuthors < 3 ) {
        valid = 1;
        printf("Got it, %d author(s).\n", NumberofAuthors);
    }
    //...
```

You never reset `valid` to `0`. You should consider using a `switch()` for that part of the while loop. It makes it more easy to read.

Also

```
if ( NumberofAuthors == 1 ) {
    printf( "Author's name: " );
    scanf("%c", &AuthorName1);

} 
if (NumberofAuthors == 2) {
    printf("First author's name: " );
    scanf("%c", &AuthorName2);
    printf("Second author's name: " );
    scanf("%c", &AuthorName3);
}
else {
    valid = 0;
}
```

I hope you realize that incase `NumberofAuthors == 1` the `else` part is going to executed and set `valid = 0`. That is because the else sticks on just the closest if, and only that.

I guess you use fgets etc to avoid overflows. Good. See that trick on the `scanf`s. Read more here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/

Try that:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char source_type;
    int NumberofAuthors;
    char AuthorName1[20];
    char AuthorName2[20];
    char AuthorName3[20];
    char title[20];
    char url[100];
    char publishingCity[20];
    char publisher[20];
    char yearPublished[20];
    char pageNumbers[20];
    int valid;

    printf("Welcome to Jackson's Chicago Manual of Style Auto-Footnoter.\n");

    printf("Choose source type:\n a.Book");
    scanf("%c" , &source_type);

    if (source_type == 'a') {
        valid = 1;
    } else {
        printf("Invalid source selection");
        valid = 0;
    }

    while ( valid == 1 && source_type == 'a' )
    {
        //Reset
        valid = 0;

        printf("Number of authors [1 or 2]: ");
        scanf( "%d", &NumberofAuthors);
        if ( NumberofAuthors > 0 && NumberofAuthors < 3 ) {
            valid = 1;
            printf("Got it, %d author(s).\n", NumberofAuthors);
        }
        else {
            printf( "That's not enough people to write a book.\n" );
            continue;
        }

        switch( NumberofAuthors )
        {
        case 1:
            printf( "Author's name: " );
            scanf("%19s", AuthorName1);
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("First author's name: " );
            scanf("%19s", AuthorName2);
            printf("Second author's name: " );
            scanf("%19s", AuthorName3);
            break;

        default:
            valid = 0;
            break;
        }

        if(valid)
        {
            printf("Book title: " );
            scanf("%19s" , title);

            printf("Publication city: " );
            scanf("%19s" , publishingCity );
        }

    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: Notice the `continue` in the first `if` in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You only change `source_type` outside of the `while` loop, so once entered the loop the only way to get out is by assigning `0` to `valid`. This is done every time `NumberofAuthors != 2`, since the first `if` is not within the `if-else` chain. Perhaps you want this instead:

```
if ( NumberofAuthors == 1 ) {
    printf( "Author's name: " );
    scanf("%c", &AuthorName1);
} else if (NumberofAuthors == 2) {
    printf("First author's name: " );
    scanf("%c", &AuthorName2);
    printf("Second author's name: " );
    scanf("%c", &AuthorName3);
} else {
    valid = 0;
}
```

Comment: It's still quitting as soon as it encounters the the first `if` within `while`. :/

Answer (score 0):

You are using `%c` to read names; this is not good.  You're passing the address of an array, rather than the pointer to the first element of the array; this is also not good.  You are trampling all over the place, and leaving yourself with undefined behaviour problems.

The 'obvious' fix is to use `%s` and forego the `&` in front of the array names, but you must not succumb to the obvious as it is wrong.  Most authors have a space between the first and last name (or initials and surname), and `%s` stops at the first space.  You need to use `fgets()` to read the names, but remember to remove the trailing newline.

It is not quite clear to me why you have a single author's name in 'AuthorName1' but double authors go in 'AuthorName2' and 'AuthorName3'; I'd expect to use 'name 1' for the first author regardless.  Indeed, it might be better to have an array of author names - that generalizes more readily.

When I compile your code (wrapping it in `int main(void) {` and `}` and including `<stdio.h>`, I get compilation warnings:

```
xx.c: In function ‘main’:
xx.c:43: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’
xx.c:43: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’
xx.c:48: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’
xx.c:48: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’
xx.c:50: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’
xx.c:50: warning: format ‘%c’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’
```

I rewrote the code to use a function to handle the prompting for and reading of strings, thus:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int get_string(const char *prompt, char *buffer, size_t bufsiz)
{
    char *nl;
    printf("%s: ", prompt);
    fflush(0);
    if (fgets(buffer, bufsiz, stdin) == 0)
        return EOF; /* Read error - EOF */
    if ((nl = strchr(buffer, '\n')) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Overlong string entered!\n");
        return EOF;
    }
    *nl = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int source_type;
    int NumberofAuthors;
    char AuthorName1[20];
    char AuthorName2[20];
    char title[20];
    char publishingCity[20];
    int valid = 0;
    int c;

    printf("Welcome to Jackson's Chicago Manual of Style Auto-Footnoter.\n");

    fputs("Choose source type:\n a.Book\n b.Journal\n c.Article\n d.Website\n ", stdout);
    source_type = getchar();

    if (source_type == 'a')
        valid = 1;
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid source selection");
        return(1);
    }

    /* Lucky that scanf() skips over the newline in search of digits! */
    while (valid == 1 && source_type == 'a')
    {
        printf("Number of authors [1 or 2]");
        scanf("%d", &NumberofAuthors);
        if (NumberofAuthors > 0 && NumberofAuthors < 3)
        {
            valid = 1;
            printf("Got it, %d author(s).\n", NumberofAuthors);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("That's not enough (or too many) people to write a book.\n");
            break;
        }
        /* Gobble to newline */
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            ;

        if (NumberofAuthors == 1)
        {
            if (get_string("Author's name", AuthorName1, sizeof(AuthorName1)) == EOF)
            {
                valid = 0;
                break;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            assert(NumberofAuthors == 2);
            if (get_string("First author's name",  AuthorName1, sizeof(AuthorName1)) == EOF ||
                get_string("Second author's name", AuthorName2, sizeof(AuthorName2)) == EOF)
            {
                valid = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (get_string("Book title", title, sizeof(title)) == EOF ||
            get_string("Publication city", publishingCity, sizeof(publishingCity)) == EOF)
        {
            valid = 0;
            break;
        }

        printf("Author 1: %s\n", AuthorName1);
        if (NumberofAuthors == 2)
            printf("Author 2: %s\n", AuthorName2);
        printf("Book title: %s\n", title);
        printf("Publication city: %s\n", publishingCity);
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

I kept the 'valid' flag, but it really doesn't pay for itself.  The code is simpler and shorter without it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I realize that this is obviously very sloppy work to a trained eye, but I'm really trying to get the hang of it. This is my first foray into writing a program from scratch and it seems I've messed up a lot. You and the others who have responded are really great and I appreciate the time you have all put into helping me. Hopefully my next submission will be less mistake-ridden.